# Как интегрировать API с сайта patreon и использовать его в игровом движке Unity (C#)?

Tags: c#, unity3d, patreon

Привет всем!
Я создаю игру в Unity. Первая часть игры будет бесплатной, но доступ ко второй части игры будет только у тех игроков, которые поддерживают меня финансово на сайте [patreon.com](http://patreon.com)
Приложению нужно получить информацию о пользователе с сайта patreon.
У этого сайта есть свой API.
Дело в том, что я начинающий программист, и я знаю английский, но не настолько хорошо, чтобы читать доккументацию ([docs.patreon.com](http://docs.patreon.com)). Я попробовал понять, что там написано, но ещё, дело в том, что там есть ссылки на скачивание API для разных языков, но не для C#, а Unity сейчас только на C#.
Подскажите, пожалуйста, если у кого есть опыть использования библиотек patreon на C#, какие материалы мне нужно знать, чтобы выполнить задачу? Или можете подсказать - как выполнить задачу, если у вас есть конкретный способ.
Спасибо!

Comment: Да там и не нужна библиотека - обращаешься по нужным адресам - скачиваешь JSON - парсишь его чем-нибудь типа JSON.NET - и работаешь как с обычными объектами C#

Comment: Спасибо за ответ. Я уже пробовал что-то подобное, но мне нужно получить данные страницы зарегистрированного пользователя. Возможно ли передать парраметры для авторизации, и где я могу прочитать об этом?

Comment: Читайте про OAuth, Патреон использует эту технологию для авторизации.

Comment: Пожалуйста, удалите из вопроса все, что не относится к конкретной технической проблеме. Саму проблему распишите подробнее, приведите пример текущего кода.